# InstantiationException: PrettyNavigationHandler

Tags: jsf, websphere, web.xml, prettyfaces

I am trying to setup a dynamic web project with Java Server Faces (2.1.7), PrettyFaces (jsf2-3.3.3), Richfaces (4.2.0) and Websphere Application Server 7. I did manage to run this configuration on several other projects, but on this new one, I seem to miss some configuration.
On application startup I always get the following exception. web.xml, pretty-config.xml and faces-config.xml looks good to me. Pls ask for code, if you think the error is in there.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Michael

```
  [1/20/15 9:35:31:308 CET] 0000000e webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                             com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED!
Source Document: wsjar:file:/C:/xxxx/yyyy/webApplication/WEB-INF/lib/prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyNavigationHandler': java.lang.InstantiationException: com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyNavigationHandler
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:212)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1681)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:374)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:731)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:616)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1122)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:609)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:725)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2046)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:949)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
Source Document: wsjar:file:/C:/xxxx/yyyy/webApplication/WEB-INF/lib/prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyNavigationHandler': java.lang.InstantiationException: com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyNavigationHandler
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:234)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.setNavigationHandler(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:331)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:94)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:132)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:202)
    ... 23 more

[1/20/15 9:35:31:417 CET] 0000000e WebContainerL I   OpenWebBeans Container is starting...
[1/20/15 9:35:31:433 CET] 0000000e PluginLoader  I   Adding OpenWebBeansPlugin : [OpenWebBeansJsfPlugin]
[1/20/15 9:35:31:448 CET] 0000000e AbstractMetaD I   added beans.xml marker: file:/C:/xxxx/yyyy/webApplication/WEB-INF/beans.xml
[1/20/15 9:35:31:901 CET] 0000000e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\KfwWebSphere7.5_7.0\logs\ffdc\server1_6e7e6e7e_15.01.20_09.35.31.8547207986182173562214.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated 1341
[1/20/15 9:35:31:901 CET] 0000000e webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                             java.lang.IllegalAccessError
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingObjectClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.isMemberClass(Class.java:2032)
    at org.apache.webbeans.util.ClassUtil.isInnerClazz(ClassUtil.java:223)
    at org.apache.webbeans.util.WebBeansUtil.isManagedBeanClass(WebBeansUtil.java:362)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.ManagedBeanConfigurator.isManagedBean(ManagedBeanConfigurator.java:91)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.defineManagedBean(BeansDeployer.java:802)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploySingleAnnotatedType(BeansDeployer.java:560)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deployFromClassPath(BeansDeployer.java:496)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:168)
    at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:128)
    at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:90)
    at org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener.contextInitialized(WebBeansConfigurationListener.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1681)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:374)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:731)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:616)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1122)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:609)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:725)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2046)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:949)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)

[1/20/15 9:35:31:979 CET] 0000000e FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\KfwWebSphere7.5_7.0\logs\ffdc\server1_6e7e6e7e_15.01.20_09.35.31.9637314861274580291662.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstance.init 181
[1/20/15 9:35:31:979 CET] 0000000e servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0100E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet Faces Servlet in application GPOrgIdentWebEAR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:270)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:358)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1809)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:1011)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:429)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:731)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:616)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1122)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:609)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:725)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2046)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:949)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)

[1/20/15 9:35:31:994 CET] 0000000e extension     E com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor createServletWrapper Error occured while preparing the servlet for initialization.
                             javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1809)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:98)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:1011)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:429)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:731)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:616)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1122)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:609)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:725)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2046)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:949)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:270)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:358)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Is there any "caused by" block in the stacktrace?

Comment: Is that really the bottommost root cause? The answer is namely in there, but the one currently shown in the question doesn't seem to represent the bottommost one.

Comment: thanks for responding balusC! added the whole trace!

Comment: I suggest to switch the dev/run environment to English. Not only so that we can also read and explain it, but English error messages yield SO MANY more Google results.

Comment: [Now copypaste it in our search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Application+was+not+properly+initialized+at+startup%2C+could+not+find+Factory%3A+javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory%22). Are the results helpful?

Comment: I saw almost all of those posts prior to asking this. Nothing really seems to help me with my problem. classpath seems to be fine, I dont want to use the WAS jsf functionality, which also works for other projects. I got the listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener as in other projects. I still seem to miss something

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your manually provided mojarra-2.1.7 jar gets used?
Otherwise it's pretty clear: prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3 is for JSF-2.0 and higher.
WebSphere-7 ships with mojarra-1.2.x means JSF-1.2. Please debug into WAS and check the signature of the classes you get.
You might need to upgrade to WebSphere-8.0.x or 8.5.x which will come with MyFaces-2.0 as JSF container.